# YouTube Player api Android

Tags: android, jar, youtube-api, libraries

I am using YouTube player api for android ti view my youtube links. However the classes in the jar file for the youTube Player states that source was not found. I followed instructions to add the jar file correctly..I done this by pasting the jar file to the libs folder and add the jar to the private libraries. Can anyone help me? thanks

Comment: Can you be more spesific, give us some code or something

Comment: on the graphical view of the xml it says - The following classes could not be instantiated:
"- com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details. "

Comment: @user3156801 Have you figured it out? I'm having the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the source code of Youtube api classes, they may not be there in the jar file. A jar file may or may not contain source code. So you will get the source code of the library only if the library is open source and they have added source code with the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the last version of the YouTube API Samples

[YouTube API Samples](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/)

I think this sample can be useful to you:

[youtube-api-samples](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/android-player/src/com/examples/youtubeapidemo/VideoListDemoActivity.java)

[image]